# Kubernetes Token Controller is not working at v1.24

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I installed vanilla kubernetes 1.24, cluster is up and healthy but when i try to install kubernetes-dashboard, i realized can not access dashboard token. Before 1.24 i just describe token and get.

Normally when sa created, secret should be created automaticaly, BUT NOW, I just tried create service account then secret not created automaticaly.

just create sa with: "kubectl create serviceaccount servicename" you should see secret as a servicename-token with kubectl get secrets. But not created..

anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question “Anyone faced this problem?”, the answer is that all the people that install version 1.24 are going to face the same behavior, as this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) indicates, this version includes features such as the ***LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration***, the one that is the root cause of what you are experiencing.

So, the workaround right now is to manually create the token, as this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-a-service-account-api-token) indicates.